# UberCart statistics on products added

Tags: drupal, statistics, ubercart

I want statistics on the products added to carts, but not checked out. I.e. if a user adds a product to his cart, but doesnt actual pay out, how can I see these products that were added? Or maybe even get notifications everytime a product is added?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an Ubercart status called 'in checkout'. An order is in this state from the time it is created until the user checksout (checkout has occurred and payment transaction completed). If a user closes the browser or leaves the site, the order is still in the ubercart system as 'in checkout'.

With that, you could create a View and look at all orders with a status of 'in checkout' and show the contents of each order.